# My Updated dhondt (political voting system) method implementation in C#

Tags: c#, object-oriented

I have took the advice on some people and improved my dhondt method calculator, which is a system that takes a file of data for a number of political parties and try to find which party to assign seats too, and this all depending on how many seats the data file wants to assign and the total votes for each party. Can someone tell me if i have used encapsulation and abstraction efficiently and if not any further tips would help thanks.

MAIN

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace Voting_System
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Make new object of file handler to get all required data and get the file path
            FileHandler partiesData = new FileHandler();
            string filePath = partiesData.getFilePath();

            // Make list of party classes to hold all parties from the sorted data
            List<Party> parties = partiesData.SortPartiesData();

            // Calculations for Dhond't method, takes list of parties and file path
            CalculateDhondt(parties, partiesData.TitleOfElection, partiesData.NumOfSeatAllocation);

            // Safely exit out the console once finished
            Console.WriteLine("\nPress any key to exit.");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }

        // Main method which calculaties which party to award seats too,and display those parties
        private static void CalculateDhondt(List<Party> parties, string electionTitle, int numOfSeatAllocations)
        {
            // Find total votes for all parties and number of seats to be allocated

            // Keep looping through partys and applying dhond't method until all seats are taken
            int totalSeatsCount = 0;
            while (totalSeatsCount != numOfSeatAllocations)
            {
                // If we havent reached desired seats count reset the total seats variable
                totalSeatsCount = 0;

                Party biggestVotes = parties.Aggregate((v1, v2) => v1.NewVotes > v2.NewVotes ? v1 : v2);
                biggestVotes.SeatsAmount += 1;
                biggestVotes.DivideParty();

                // Check total seats for all parties
                foreach (Party party in parties)
                {
                    totalSeatsCount += party.SeatsAmount;
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"\n{numOfSeatAllocations} seats successfully allocated :\n{electionTitle}");

            // Display parties who are awarded a seat
            foreach(Party p in parties)
            {
                if(p.HasSeats())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(p);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

FILE HANDLER class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace Voting_System
{
    class FileHandler
    {
        public string FilePath { get; private set; }
        public string TitleOfElection { get; private set; }
        public int NumOfSeatAllocation { get; private set; }

        // Takes input of the name of the data file and outputs the required data
        public List<Party> SortPartiesData()
        {
            // Reads from the data file the user inputs
            List<string> file = File.ReadAllLines(Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(@"..\..\..\..\" + FilePath))).ToList();
            List<Party> parties = new List<Party>();

            NumOfSeatAllocation = Convert.ToInt32(file[1]);
            TitleOfElection = file[0];

            // Store required values from data file for each party in a list of Party class
            foreach (string line in file.Skip(3))
            {
                string[] items = line.Split(',');
                Party p = new Party(items[0], Convert.ToInt32(items[1]), items.Skip(2).ToArray());
                parties.Add(p);
            }
            return parties;
        }

        public string getFilePath()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Type the name of the text file your data is held : ");
            string fileName = Console.ReadLine() + ".txt";
            FilePath = fileName;
            return FilePath;
        }
    }
}
```

PARTY class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Voting_System
{
    class Party
    {
        // Fields
        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public int Votes { get; private set; }
        public int NewVotes { get; private set; }
        public string[] SeatsCodeValues { get; private set; }

        private int _seatsAmount;

        // Properties 
        public int SeatsAmount
        {
            get { return _seatsAmount; }
            set
            {
                if (value > 0)
                {
                    _seatsAmount = value;
                }
            }
        }

        // Constructor for party class,which takes inputs and assigns them to properties
        public Party(string name, int votes, string[] seatsCodeValues)
        {
            Name = name;
            Votes = votes;
            NewVotes = votes;
            SeatsCodeValues = seatsCodeValues;
        }

        // Returns percentage of votes for your party
        public double PercentOfVotes(double totalVotes) => (Votes / totalVotes) * 100;

        // When ever you print the object of this class return this
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"Name: {Name}, Votes: {Votes} - {string.Join(",", SeatsCodeValues.Take(SeatsAmount))};";
        }

        // Applies Dhond't method of division 
        public void DivideParty() => NewVotes = Votes / (1 + SeatsAmount);

        public bool HasSeats() => SeatsAmount > 0 ? true : false;
    }
}
```

INPUT DATA FILE

```
#East Midlands (European Parliament Constituency)
5
1183227
Brexit Party,452321,BP1,BP2,BP3,BP4,BP5;
Liberal Democrats,203989,LD1,LD2,LD3,LD4,LD5;
Labour,164682,LAB1,LAB2,LAB3,LAB4,LAB5;
Conservative,126138,CON1,CON2,CON3,CON4,CON5;
Green,124630,GR1,GR2,GR3,GR4,GR5;
UKIP,58198,UKP1,UKP2,UKP3,UKP4,UKP5;
Change UK,41117,CUK1,CUK2,CUK3,CUK4,CUK5;
Independent Network,7641,INET1,INET2,INET3,INET4,INET5;
Independent,4511,IND1;
```

Comment: @BCdotWEB my bad,fixed now

Answer (score 1):

Here are some of my observations:

#### `Main`

- `string filePath = partiesData.getFilePath();`

  - `filePath` is unused because the method has a side effect (it sets the `FilePath` property)
  - `getFilePath` should be renamed to `GetFilePath`
- `//Make list of party classes to hold all parties from the sorted data`

  - Please do not comment each line
  - If you think that your method does not have expressive name than rename it
  - Comment should capture the **why**s and **why not**s
  - The **what** and **how** should be clear from your code
- `Environment.Exit(0);`

  - It is unnecessary because that's the default return value
  - This method is useful when you early exit (for example some precondition is not met)

#### `CalculateDhondt`

- `List<Party> parties`: If you want to express your intent that you don't want to change the parameter then you can use `IReadOnlyCollection<Party> parties`
- The calculation and the display logic are still inside the same method.

  - Either split it or rename it to reflect its implementation.
- `totalSeatsCount` calculation can be simplified:

  - `totalSeatsCount = parties.Sum(party => party.SeatsAmount)`
- `foreach` + `if` can be combined:

```cs
foreach (var party in parties.Where(p => p.HasSeats())) Console.WriteLine(party);
```

#### `FileHandler`

- Its name is way too general although its implementation is way too specific
- `SortPartiesData`: I can't see any sorting so its name is misleading

  - `ParseParties` might be sufficient
- `List<string> file`: `ReadAllLines` returns an array of string, which is sufficient in this case

  - So, do not call `ToList`
- `Path.Combine(@"..\..\..\..\" + FilePath)`:

  - This is super fragile and super specific
  - You have assumed that the `FilePath` has been set via `getFilePath`.
  - You can't make this kind of assumptions because you don't know how your users will call your methods.

    - Will they call at all?
    - Will they call in the appropriate order?????
  - If you allow to your users to specify the file name then please make sure that the given file exist before you try to work with it.

    - [all input is evil until proven otherwise](https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/writing-secure-code/0735617228/ch10.html).
- `NumOfSeatAllocation = Convert.ToInt32(file[1])`: Yet again extremely fragile.

  - You trust blindly on the position of the data and its type as well.
  - Don't do that please check, check and check.
- The whole `foreach` can be rewritten with the following LINQ:

  - *It has a lots of assumptions as well*

```cs
return file.Skip(3)
    .Select(line => line.Split(','))
    .Select(items => new Party(items[0], Convert.ToInt32(items[1]), items.Skip(2).ToArray()))
    .ToList();
```

#### `Party`

- `private set`: You can remove all of these except the one which is used at the `NewVotes`
- `//Fields`: These are properties as well
- `PercentOfVotes`: This method is unused
- `if (value > 0)`: Why do you need this?

---

**UPDATE**: `List` vs `IReadOnlyCollection`

There is a well-known security principle: [least privilege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege). It says that we should aim for the minimal set of rights. For example: if we don't want to modify something then it is enough for acquiring only read rights.

In this particular case IReadOnlyCollection says that the collection itself is immutable from the method perspective. So, we can't add new items or remove existing ones from it.

Why is this good? In case of concurrency multiple threads can read the same collection if they are not modifying it. If the method itself tells to the consumer that it won't change the collection then it will help the consumer to be able to decide whether or not additional synchronization is needed or not.

On the other hand there is another well-known principle: [Postel's Law](https://devopedia.org/postel-s-law) : *Be liberal in what you accept, and conservative in what you send*. In other words you should accept `IEnumerable` and return with `IReadOnlyCollection`.

At the first sight it may seem contradictory. But if you return with an IReadOnlyCollection from the `SortPartiesData` then it make sense.

Comment: Thanks for the help! , regarding the IReadOnlyCollection<Party> parties can you explain why this is needed? bit confused.Also the data given to us has been said it will always been in the exact same format so that why its kind of hard coded. But thank you for all the other adivce!

Comment: Would you suggest changing Path.Combine(@"..\..\..\..\" + FilePath): and putting the file into bin>debug and just using File.ReadAllLines("input.txt"); instead.

Comment: @Mj_ I've extended my answer with details about `List` vs `IReadOnlyCollection`, please check it.

Comment: If you specify the `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy Always` then the file reside next to the application. If you want to provide flexibility then accept absolute path (as the user input) and then call [File.Exists](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.exists). If it does not exist then ask a new one until the user provides a valid file path.

Comment: Or even simpler: `parties.Where(x => x.HasSeats()).Select(x => Console.WriteLine(x))`